# CSS Border weird behavior (0.990px instead of 1px)

Tags: css, border

On the following website: www.finelovedolls.com my CSS borders are all coded to be 1px, but recently borders started behaving weirdly, I cannot figure out why.

In Chrome inspector tool, they are all said to measure 0.990px instead of 1px, and often either the top, bottom, left or right border is missing

The best way to replicate the issue is on the menu >> Shop >> Newest Dolls

Any idea why? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the original.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. In my case, it was because I was zoomed in on the page. So try to reset your zoom level by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and see if it helps.